# WinAPI BitBlt freezes for minutes

Tags: c++, windows, qt, winapi, screenshot

I have a little modified [QScreen::grabWindow](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/windows/qwindowsscreen.cpp.html#_ZNK14QWindowsScreen10grabWindowEyiiii) function. And on some computers, unfortunately I didn't find relationship between them, BitBlt freezes for even minutes! Why this can happen and what can I do?

```
QPixmap DetectionFlow::grabScreen(HWND h)
{
    RECT rect;
    GetClientRect(h, (LPRECT)&rect);

    // get the height and width of the screen
    int height = rect.bottom - rect.top;
    int width = rect.right - rect.left;

    // Create and setup bitmap
    HDC display_dc = GetDC(0);

    HDC bitmap_dc = CreateCompatibleDC(display_dc);

    HBITMAP bitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(display_dc, width, height);

    HGDIOBJ null_bitmap = SelectObject(bitmap_dc, bitmap);

    HDC window_dc = GetDC(h);
    BitBlt(bitmap_dc, 0, 0, width, height, window_dc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    // clean up all but bitmap
    ReleaseDC(h, window_dc);

    SelectObject(bitmap_dc, null_bitmap);

    DeleteDC(bitmap_dc);


    const QPixmap pixmap = qt_pixmapFromWinHBITMAP(bitmap);

    DeleteObject(bitmap);

    ReleaseDC(0, display_dc);

    return pixmap;
}
```

PS. What is interesting, on computers, where freezes, it freezes randomly. So usually there it works fast (a couple of ms) and then freeze.

Comment: *Why this can happen* -- Aren't functions such as `BitBlt` highly dependent on the device / hardware you're using?  What works on one device may not work on another (that's why there is a *device context* parameter).   Also, why are you not checking the return values for the Win API calls?  Since you're running this on different computers, it is practically mandatory to check return values from Win API calls.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It's Qt code. why not checking? I don't know exactly, but as I know, that functions can't fail with exception.
With device interesting idea, but not helpful. It's not ok that such functions freezes for 3 mins. Must be reason why.

Comment: It is helpful, and the reason why I know this is that I personally had to debug code where device context related functions were failing for particular devices (in my case, printers).  Without checking return codes, you are just assuming that those functions "work".  Again, since you plan on running this on various computers, it is imperative you check return codes.  You are missing [a lot of info if the function fails](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183370%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie in my task it is ok to not receive screen a couple of times. Problem in freezing, not incorrect work or bad screens. That methods should not freeze for 3 (!!!) mins in any case.

Comment: In addition, you need to know the exact devices that are not working correctly.  Model, version, etc.  Again, these functions that use device contexts that represent hardware may, and probably will, work differently depending on the device's information.

Comment: And I had printers printing totally black pages, and other printers working ok with the same code.  By checking the return values, I discovered that the device context related functions were returning `FALSE` for the printers that were not working correctly.  In your case, maybe the device has slow memory -- again, you need to know what the display device's information is.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie 
"Again, these functions that use device contexts that represent hardware may, and probably will, work differently depending on the device's information." <------ 3 minutes on screen (1280x720) grabbing? Are you seriously? Such time can be only when something very serious happens, not "working differently". For example, when some race or deadlock happens. Don't answer if you don't know.

Comment: You don't even want to check your return values.  What else is there to tell you?  You're flying blind if you're not logging return codes and / or pin down the hardware where this is not working.

Comment: It's code from official Qt repository. If you thinks that that values is some important, maybe then you will create bug in bug tracker?

Comment: If it is from the Qt repository, the link to BitBlt should be the bug report, since this Qt code is lacking support for error checking.  Code like this should check return values, since 1) It doesn't know what the display hardware may be, thus those functions may fail and 2) Any responsible Win API programmer that releases code that is meant to be used by other programmers would log and check all API return codes.  I was burned by this type of lazy coding in the past, and on the device context part too.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Can you understand that ALL FUNCTIONS WORKS, but sometimes RANDOMLY on the same PC IT WORKS 3 MINUTES???? Is that simple thing too hard for you?

Comment: Stop shouting.  Here is what you posted: --  `And on some computers,`.  I am giving you advice that I personally ran into with code similar to this.  You can take it or leave it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It's not shouting, I've marked the most hard for your understanding parts.

Comment: Capitalized words are considered shouting in the Internet world.  Secondly, I spent my time trying to give you advice, but since you don't what to heed any of it, then keep waiting for someone else to respond to you.

Comment: They mean what the author wants to mean.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903043/total-system-freezing-when-using-timers-in-graphical-application check examples of good answers, not for reputation.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you spent time for reputation hunt, not for advice.

Comment: Reputation is gained by posting answers, not comments.  I get absolutely no points placing comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in Aero. Computers that freezes with BitBlt has Win7 and Aero. Without Aero all ok.